# Font awesome disappearing in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, font-awesome

As of today my font-awesome icons started disappearing on my website. I updated the theme ( [upside theme - kopathemes](http://upsidethemes.net/demo/upside/kidhouse/) ) and WordPress to latest 4.7;

So far this happens in Chrome. Firefox displays everything correctly.

What to do ?

Comment: It's look working in my chrome 66, where is the problem ?

Comment: @GuptaAnirudha try this site : dev.svetasofia.com ; is it working

Comment: are you modifying something in JS to do something. it's working but later it's gone.

Comment: @GuptaAnirudha yes I know and no I am not modifying anything. And to temporary fix this open up the console, find an icon and turn any style off and on again and it works ... I don't know ...

Comment: try to put it in the end of css to just test if it's working or not? @mp3por

Comment: @GuptaAnirudha no idea how to do this in WordPress

Answer (score 0):

#I had also taken wordpress update and lost the font-awesome#

What I did:

I just do these steps:

Step1:  Link the CDN via wp_enqueue_script function in my theme's functions.php file.
https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css

Make sure the version compatibility also with i tags that you will use for the font integration.

Step2: simple put the i tags with correct icon code where I want to use the font awesome's icon.

Hope this will work for you :) .